# AWS Lambda: How I can skip first index in "For loop" in python for my situation?

Tags: python, for-loop, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I wrote a python script in lambda, in which I am fetching S3 CSV files and putting data into DynamoDb. Everything is going great but I want to skip the 0 index of my loop and don't know how to perform that action in my situation. Following is my code:

```
    import json 
    import boto3
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    student_table = dynamodb.Table('s3todynamodb')
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)

    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)

    students = file_content.split("\n")
    print("students :",students)
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        print(data[0])
        print(data[1])
        print(data[2])
        print(data[3])
        print(data[4])
        print(data[5])
        print(data[6])
        print(data[7])
        print(data[8])
        print(data[9])
        print(data[10])
        print(data[11])
        print(data[12])
        print(data[13])
        print(data[14])
        print(data[15])
        print(data[16])
        print(data[17])
        print(data[18])
        student_table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "Agent" : data[0],
                "Agent answer rate" : data[1],
                "Agent idle time" : data[2],
                "Contacts missed" : data[3],
                "Agent on contact time" : data[4],
                "Nonproductive time" : data[5],
                "Occupancy" : data[6],
                "Online time" : data[7],
                "Average after contact work time" : data[8],
                "Average agent interaction time" : data[9],
                "Average customer hold time" : data[10],
                "Average handle time" : data[11],
                "Contacts handled" : data[12],
                "Contacts handled incoming" : data[13],
                "Contacts handled outbound" : data[14],
                "Contacts put on hold" : data[15],
                "Contacts transferred out" : data[16],
                "Contacts transferred out external" : data[17],
                "Contacts transferred out internal" : data[18]
                }
            )
```

There is also second issue while running this code, although it is working properly but every time it executes, it throws an error that is mentioned below:

[image: 'list index out of range" Error]

First problem = Start for loop from 1
Second problem = Index list out of range error.

I would be very grateful if anyone provides any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tip use a for loop to print out your data to improve the readability and efficiency of your code writing. Like this one `for item in data : print(item)`

Answer (score 2):

For the fist one you can do:

```
for student in students[1:]:
```

The second issue is on line 23, which is one of the

```
print(data[X])
```

Not quite sure which one exactly, as your code doesn't show lines. You have to print out the data (without index) to check for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You almost assuredly are hitting on an empty line, causing your final `student.split(",")` to return a one element array.

Rather than parsing the CSV manually, it would be much easier to use the built-in Python module to parse it for you:

```
from csv import DictReader
from io import StringIO
for Item in DictReader(StringIO(file_content)):
    print(Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for student in students:
```

with

```
for index, student in enumerate(students):
    if index == 0:
        continue
```